# Replace $scope with this by turning on ControllerAs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I thought to replace `$scope` with `this` keyword in my sample Angular code base and in turn to switch to using `ControllerAs` syntax.

But in turn this does not seem to work now.

I have a list of countries in my `controller` and in my `custom directive` whenever a country name is clicked , I show the map of the `respective country`.

```
<body ng-controller="appCtrl as vm">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Welcome to the world of directives!</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li ng-repeat="countryTab in vm.countries" ng-click="vm.itemClicked(countryTab)" style="cursor:pointer">
                <a>{{countryTab.label}}</a>
            </li>
            <br>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<data-country-tab-bar country="vm.selectedCountry"  ng-if="vm.selectedCountry">
    <strong><i>Check out our cool new directive!</i></strong>
</data-country-tab-bar>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('app',[]);
    app.controller('appCtrl',function($scope,$http){
        this.countries = [{
          id: 1,
          label: 'Italy',
          coords: '41.29246,12.5736108'
        }, {
          id: 2,
          label: 'Japan',
          coords: '37.4900318,136.4664008'
        }, {
          id: 3,
          label: 'USA',
          coords: '37.6,-95.665'
        }, {
          id: 4,
          label: 'India',
          coords: '20.5937,78.9629'
        }];

        this.itemClicked = function(value){
            this.selectedCountry = value;
        }


    });
```

And in my directive , I just bind `the country object that is the part of my DDO's isolated scope , to that of the controller's`.

```
        app.directive('countryTabBar',function(){
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                transclude:true,
                replace:true,
                $scope:{
                    country: '='
                },
                template: '<div>'+
                '   <div><strong>{{country.label }}</strong> : {{ country.coords}}</div>'+
                '   <br/>'+
                '   <img ng-src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center={{country.coords}}&zoom=4&size=800x200"> '+      
                '   <br/><br/>'+
                '   <div ng-transclude></div>'+
                '</div>',
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

But , I can see the transcluded string `Check out our cool new directive!` but I can't see the map.

There is no error as such in console.

Please help.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the transcluded string". It looks to me like you're just seeing the string you put inside the directive tag, but the directive isn't activating/processing. It's just dead HTML.

If so, I've seen that happen because either the directive markup uses the directive name incorrectly (ab-cd instead of a-b-c-d, etc) or the directive isn't injected into the component that's trying to use it. So the tag is in the template, the template renders, but the directive does nothing. There are no console errors to tell you this is what's happening, it's just an Angular black hole.

Comment: `{{country.label }}` is printing the value ?

Comment: @atulquest93 .. No it is not . Neither is the `img` coming. I guess this has something to do how I pass `vm.selectedCountry` to the directive's scope object .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is related to:

```
this.itemClicked = function(value){
  this.selectedCountry = value;
}
```

this.selectedCountry in a function declared so in JavaScript will refer to the current function, not the controller (parent function) as you expect.

Solution (ES5):

```
var vm = this;
this.itemClicked = function(value){
  vm.selectedCountry = value;
}
```

Solution (ES6):

```
this.itemClicked = value => this.selectedCountry = value;
```

Additionally, the directive scope syntax seems to be incorrect:

```
$scope:{
  country: '='
},
```

Should be:

```
scope:{
  country: '='
},
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the mistake. But still I cant see `<img ng-src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center={{country.coords}}&zoom=4&size=800x200"> `  working . Neither `{{country.label}}` is working.

Comment: See edit (I think another problem is that `$scope` should be `scope` in you directive definition).